# How can I get the bootstrap hover effect?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

When I hover over login button it becomes white. I want normal twitter bootstrap when I hover. There is something in my CSS that changes the bootstrap behavior. Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/niklasro/wr7w87as/) with the problem. I create my button like this `<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Login</button>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the line that is causing the problem :

```
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgb(229, 229, 229), rgb(244, 244, 244));
```

It is applied on `hover` of `button`, `input[type="submit"]` and `input[type="button"]`. Search your CSS file and get rid/edit that line.